# How can i draw a combination diagram?

Tags: diagrams

I need help making this types of diagrams

[image]

I tried to use \frac but it doesn't work because I need the equal symbol to be on top, also I tried to use \underline but I don't know if there is some way to put text below.

I've been thinking I could do it with \tikz, but I wanted to see if there's an easier way.

Comment: What do you mean by "combination diagram"? I see an equation and not a diagram (but I am not a mathematician).

Comment: If my above comment makes sense to you then please update the title to make it more meaningful for others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an invisible fraction based on `\genfrac` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ifrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{52}{1^\circ}\ifrac{\cdot}{}\frac{51}{2^\circ}\ifrac{\cdots}{}\frac{1}{52^\circ}\ifrac{=52!}{}\]    
or
\[\frac{52}{1^\circ}\ifrac{\cdot}{}\frac{51}{2^\circ}\ifrac{\cdots}{\cdots}\frac{1}{52^\circ}\ifrac{=52!}{}\]    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!, It's easier than I had thought.

Answer (score 0):

Following [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)'s answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129823/how-to-vertically-shift-the-sign):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myVerticalRaise}{1.5ex} % Variable for vertical raise used in \raisebox. 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \frac{52}{1} \mathrel{\raisebox{\myVerticalRaise}{$\cdot$}}%
   \frac{51}{2} \mathrel{\raisebox{\myVerticalRaise}{$\cdot$}}%
   \frac{1}{52} %
   \mathrel{\raisebox{\myVerticalRaise}{$=52!$}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```